# Java. Praoblem with org.json

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, org.json

I have Json string, which contain "key" : "value" pairs and i need to know keys at this string  using Java and importing org.json. I tried to use iterator, but first pair key prints in the end.

for example string:

```
{
   "firstName": "sam",
   "lastName": "Smith",
   "address": {
       "streetAddress": "somestreet",
       "city": "somecity",
       "postalCode": 101101
   },
   "phoneNumbers": [
       "812 123-1234",
       "916 123-4567"
   ]
}
```

I want to print:
"
firstName
lastName
address
phoneNumbers
".
But i have: 
"lastName
address
phoneNumbers
firstName"

```
 JSONObject JO = new JSONObject(JsonString);
    Iterator<String> It = JO.keys();

       while (It.hasNext()){        
       System.out.println(It.next());
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [JavaDoc](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html):

> A JSONObject is an unordered collection of name/value pairs.

If you want to order the keys you must 1) place them in a list and 2) order the list according your needs. Keep in mind that this is a key/value representation of data - the sequence of elements should not matter.

Answer (score 2):

Using json-simple you can do this using the following code

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class TestJsonKeys {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        final String jsonText = "{\n" + "   \"firstName\": \"sam\",\n" + "   \"lastName\": \"Smith\",\n"
                + "   \"address\": {\n" + "       \"streetAddress\": \"somestreet\",\n"
                + "       \"city\": \"somecity\",\n" + "       \"postalCode\": 101101\n" + "   },\n"
                + "   \"phoneNumbers\": [\n" + "       \"812 123-1234\",\n" + "       \"916 123-4567\"\n" + "   ]\n"
                + "}";
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonText);
        System.out.println(json.keySet());
    }
}
```